# Node.js API Gateway & nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, api, nginx, gateway

I've recently started creating an application using the microservice architecture, as the app evolves the line that divides the concepts of a reverse proxy and an API Gateway fades for me: 
I want to use nginx to handle load balancing & reverse proxying, but I also want to use an API Gateway so the clients don't know every microservice in the architecture, (among other things).

So now I'm stuck with the chicken & the egg issue, I've been thinking about what comes first :

1. Request > API Gateway > nginx.
2. Request > nginx > API Gateway.

I tend to think its number 1 but in that case, nginx wouldn't be the entry point of the application... (is that a problem?)

Comment: See Similar generic question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756663/api-gateway-vs-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API gateways comes with lots of features like throttling, cache, cors etc. Many use API Gateways to call different micro-services and combine the result at API Gateway level (I do not prefer it though). You can also do API version management with some of the API gateway tools.

Load balancing should come only after you have decided which API to call or block that API or which version of the API to call.

So option 1 looks right to me.

Comment: I agree with you but in this part "Many use API Gateways to call different micro-services and combine the result at API Gateway level (I do not prefer it though)." - how would you do it then ? isn't it better to combine a lightweight result of let's say 20 microservices & then send back one single response rather than sending back 20 single responses ?

Comment: I would have one micro-service, call the rest of the 19. The problem with combining at API gateway layer is hard to debug, not part of source control and one more place to debug in case of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should opt for option 2. Here is why:

1. API gateways are generally not designed to handle a potential DOS attack, having nginx infornt of your gateway removes that worry from mind.
2. Most API gateways are route based, if you opt for subdomains, option 1 will only work with some gateways but 2 will work for all.
3. A reverse proxy like nginx is built with performance in mind, and can handle more requests at lesser costs. Having a Node.js infront of a much higher performant server is a bottleneck!

An API gateway is technically a "specialized" reverse proxy. So eventually you will realize tasks can be performed by either   .